# Firefox shortcuts are overriding all other windows' keyboard shortcuts

Tags: firefox, keyboard-shortcuts, hotkeys

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Firefox is capturing Ctrl + Shift  + g from Eclipse](https://superuser.com/questions/116008/firefox-is-capturing-ctrl-shift-g-from-eclipse)

For example, if I am in [Eclipse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_%28software%29), and I hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>, Eclipse will not pick up the shortcut and Firefox will launch with a new tab or create a new tab in the current window and switch focus. It also happens even when Firefox is not running.

Basically, if I select text and hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>, Firefox will open a new tab with a search for the selected text. This prevents me from using other programs (like Eclipse) since Firefox is consuming the shortcut event and not the intended program.

Comment: Which shortcuts? On the desktop? Keyboard shortcuts? What do you mean by "overriding"? Please edit your question with more details so we can be of more help.

Comment: So, there is no `firefox.exe` process at all (Task Manager) when this happens? Have you tried restarting the computer?

Comment: @iglzx Yes to both

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[It's not Firefox that's doing that.](https://superuser.com/questions/116008/firefox-is-capturing-ctrl-shift-g-from-eclipse).

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> in Firefox will open the in-document search functionality.

You have some tool installed that will perform a Google search for whatever text you have selected in your default browser.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to disable directly all firefox keyboard shortcuts however you can customize/remove them with a firefox addon (just google for "customize firefox shortcuts addon"). Still this should not affect shortcuts outside firefox, as iglvzx said check the task manager to see if firefox is runing.

Comment: I don't want to turn off the short cuts in FF. I want FF to stop intercepting them when other windows are active.